# Spark Streaming - Join on multiple kafka stream operation is slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have 3 kafka streams having 600k+ records each, spark streaming takes more than 10 mins to process simple joins between streams.

Spark Cluster config:

[image: Spark Master UI]

This is how i'm reading kafka streams to tempviews in spark(scala)

```
spark.read
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "KAFKASERVER")
.option("subscribe", TOPIC1)
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.option("endingOffsets", "latest").load()
.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as json")
.select( from_json($"json", schema=SCHEMA1).as("data"))
.select($"COL1", $"COL2")
.createOrReplaceTempView("TABLE1")
```

I join 3 TABLES using spark spark sql

```
select COL1, COL2 from TABLE1   
JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.PK = TABLE2.PK
JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.PK = TABLE3.PK
```

Execution of Job:

[image: Job UI]

Am i missing out some configuration on spark that i've to look into?

Comment: This might be due to very low partitioning of the Kafka topic resulting in low parallelism in spark. How many partitions your Kafka topic has? And how many executors you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I find the same problem. And I found join between stream and stream needs more memory as I image. And the problem  disappear when I increase the cores per executor.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there wasn't any test data nor the result data that you expected to be so I could play with, so I cannot give the exact proper answer.

@Asteroid comment is valid, as we see the number of task for each stage is 1. Normally Kafka stream use receiver to consume the topic; and each receiver only create one tasks. One approach is to use multiple receivers / split partition / Increase your resources (# of core) to increase parallelism.

If this still not working, another way is to use Kafka API to createDirectStream. According to the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils.html, this one creates an input stream that directly pulls messages from Kafka Brokers without using any receiver.

I premilinary crafted a sample code for creating direct stream below. You might want to learn about this to customize to you own preference.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "KAFKASERVER",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "startingOffsets" -> "earliest",
  "endingOffsets" -> "latest"
)

val topics = Array(TOPIC1)
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)
val schema = StructType(StructField('data', StringType, True))
val df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
val dstream = stream.map(_.value())
dstream.forEachRDD(){rdd:RDD[String], time:Time} => {
    val tdf = spark.read.schema(schema).json(rdd)
    df = df.union(tdf)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("TABLE1")
}
```

Some related materials:

https://mapr.com/blog/monitoring-real-time-uber-data-using-spark-machine-learning-streaming-and-kafka-api-part-2/ (Scroll down to Kafka Consumer Code portion. The other section is irrelevant)

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html (Spark Doc for create direct stream)

Good luck!